# Doctrine2 - add to product entity parameter with value

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, mapping

Please, could you help me?

I´m looking for the best way, how to add to entity (Product) some parametrs with values.

For example:
Product T-Shirt would have parametrs: size: XXL, color: red, material: cotton. How to make tables to have the best result - easy adding parametrs to product and easy filtering products by parametrs.

Thank you for your opinions.

Comment: You should define all those fields as choices, in order to allow only certain strings to be persisted to the database. Take a look at this: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Choice.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was thinking now once more and I probably finded out quite good way - I will use NestedTree and define some parameter and as children I added values. Than I just connect product with childrens ( = parameters values) I want... What do you think about it?

Comment: It could work, but I don't know if it's the best option. If I understood your first question, you are trying to have a `Product` object with some properties like `size` which could contain `[XS, S, M, L, XL, ...]` and similar properties. I don't think you need to nest anything. If you just constraint the options (only `XS, S, M, L, XL` for the `size`) it wouldn't be a problem. Apart of this, you may do some simple queries with `DISTINCT` to filter, and similar stuff. Did I answered your question?

Comment: Yeah, your solution looks great. But won´t be faster the solution with mapping? What is your opinion about this?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what you mean with "the solution with mapping".

Comment: By mapping I mean: I create parameters and values - TreeRepository, and than to set product parameter values I will use coupling table.

Comment: Sorry, but I cannot figure out how could be by the way are your saying. All I can do is invite you to try the way I suggested you.

Comment: It´s ok. Thank you for your help. I will use it as solution of my problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:

**A OneToMany relationship with another entity (recommended)**

You may create a new entity called ProductProperty and declare a OneToMany relationship from Product to ProductProperty, like this:

The Product entity

```
/** 
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Product
{

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ProductProperty", mappedBy="product", cascade={"remove"})
     */
    public $properties;

}
```

The ProductProperty entity

```
/** 
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class ProductProperty
{

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Product", inversedBy="properties")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="product_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    public $product;

}
```

**Create an array property in entity Product**

Doctrine 2 supports arrays (it serializes the array into a TEXT column). Create a property that behaves like an array:

```
/** 
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Product
{

    /** @ORM\Column(type="array") */
    public $properties;

    public function __construct()
    {

        $this->properties = []; //new PHP array notation, if using older PHP use array()

    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution and your time. This solution looks as good way for me.